# calling a java script function on another page using php

Tags: javascript, php

i am working on google map api.
i've created a function named as codeAddress which shows the map of state/city given by user in a text field named on a click event (button name show map). I want to show the map on another page on a click of same button. please help me how can i call the codeAddress function on another page?

Comment: I am not really shure what youre expecting... You can do that with a link with target="_blank" on same url (To your PHP file (?with GET Data?)). Please write a little bit more about it!

Comment: Do you only want to reload current map with new user data? Then the solution is ajax (e.g. with jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implement Client-Client protocol. Unfortunately, you'll need third part in this system^ server. There is several options:

1. Long polling from the second page to server-side Stack. Stack is abstract storage with function name and arguments. First page puts function to the stack (simple AJAX request) and maximum after a polling lag the second page will receive this Stack item.
2. Use server as connector and make peer-to-peer connection. After this you'll be able to send messages to the opened pipe.
3. Use something like socket.io - Pub-Sub pattern realization written in Javascript (Node.js)

All these options are not trivial and requires some additional work.